# SwiftUI: Detect NavigationView goes back to main view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-view, xcode14.3

I have a `NavigationView` and the following view structure `ViewA -> ViewB -> ViewC` and I'm trying to figure out how to detect when ViewB goes back to ViewA`ViewB -> ViewA`. Here is my Code:

```
struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink{
                ViewB()
            }label: {
                Text("Go to ViewB")
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink{
            ViewC()
        }label: {
            Text("Go to ViewC")
        }
        .onAppear{
            print("onAppear \(presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented)")
        }
        .onDisappear{
            print("onDisappear \(presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented)")
        }
    }
}

struct ViewC: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ViewC")
    }
}
```

With the following code:

```
        .onAppear{
            print("onAppear \(presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented)")
        }
        .onDisappear{
            print("onDisappear \(presentationMode.wrappedValue.isPresented)")
        }
```

with the code above I can detect when ViewC goes ViewB (per console output `onAppear true`). But my question is how can detect when `ViewB -> ViewA`.

Any of you knows how can accomplish this or if there is a way around to detect this?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: why not do the same in `ViewA` as you do in `ViewB`. In `ViewA` add
 `.onAppear{ print("----> onAppear ViewA") }` and
 `.onDisappear{ print("----> onDisappear ViewA") }`
 The combination of disappearing from a view and appearing in another should
 give you a way to determine going from `ViewB` to `ViewA`. Note however, that `NavigationView` is deprecated and you should use `NavigationStack` that would make all this much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Though both of approaches are correct, mentioned by @ChrisR is also working well. If i was working on it i would have used `environmentObject` something like below approach. Hope it helps. Working well tested on Xcode 14.3

```
class NavigationLinkDestination: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentView: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var navigationLinkDest = NavigationLinkDestination()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink{
                ViewB()
            }label: {
                Text("Go to ViewB").onAppear {
                    navigationLinkDest.currentView = "ViewA"
                    print("current view \(navigationLinkDest.currentView)")
                }
                
            }
        }.environmentObject(navigationLinkDest)
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationLinkDest: NavigationLinkDestination
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink{
            ViewC()
        }label: {
            Text("Go to ViewC").onAppear {
                navigationLinkDest.currentView = "View B"
                print("current view \(navigationLinkDest.currentView)")
            }
        }.environmentObject(navigationLinkDest)
    }
}


struct ViewC: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationLinkDest: NavigationLinkDestination
    var body: some View {
        Text("ViewC").onAppear {
            navigationLinkDest.currentView = "View C"
            print(navigationLinkDest.currentView)
        }.environmentObject(navigationLinkDest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on the new `NavigationStack` which lets you record the navigation path (as @workingdog mentioned):

```
struct ViewA: View {
    
    @State private var navigationPath: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
            NavigationLink(value: "B") {
                Text("Go to ViewB")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { destination in
                if destination == "B" {
                    ViewB()
                } else {
                    ViewC()
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: navigationPath) { newValue in
            print(newValue)
            if newValue == [] {
                print("Coming from ViewB to ViewA") // trigger your action here
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: "C") {
            Text("Go to ViewC")
        }
    }
}

struct ViewC: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("ViewC")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using `NavigationView` for compatibility with iOS 15 and earlier, then you can reliably be notified when `ViewB` is popped by making the state of `ViewA`’s `NavigationLink` explicit.

You used the [`NavigationLink(destination:label:)` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destination:label:)-27n7s), which means the `NavigationLink` has a hidden flag that tracks whether it is active or not.

Instead, store that flag yourself, and use a custom `Binding` with the [`NavigationLink(isActive:destination:label:)` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(isactive:destination:label:)) to be notified when the `NavigationView` activates or deactivates the link.

```
struct ViewA: View {
    @State var linkIsActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(isActive: Binding(
                get: { linkIsActive },
                set: {
                    if $0 != linkIsActive {
                        linkIsActive = $0
                        print($0 ? "pushing ViewB" : "popping ViewB")
                    }
                }
            )) {
                ViewB()
            } label: {
                Text("Go to ViewB")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a nice one!